# where do i find the drivers for a F5D7000 Belkin wireless adapter?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

So I plugged an F5D7000 Belkin desktop wireless adapter into my desktop. Here is a picture of it:

[image: NIC]

I did a Google search and found the [**drivers**](http://www.belkin.com/support/article/?lid=en&aid=6001).  I installed the latest version - (F5D7000 - Driver - Version 8xxx), and the NIC is still unrecognized as per the next screenshot:[image: Software]

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this working?  I'm running Windows XP SP3 32-bit.

(I have taken a screenshot but without network connectivity I can't email it or post it anywhere and I don't have a USB stick.)

Comment: click on details and look for the hardware ID. Use this ID to see which chip the card has and google for drivers for this chip.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you tried to install the wrong driver.  It looks like you have a v1xxx, which has a different driver from the rest.
The link here should help: http://www.belkin.com/us/support-article?rnId=303
Try that first driver listed and see if that helps.